# C# Binary Search

Tags: c#

```
public int BinarySearch(int x)
{
    //if (Attendees.Length == 0)
    //    return -1;
    int mid =  (Count/ 2) -1;
    Student cur = new Student(x);

    while (cur.CompareTo(Attendees[mid]) != 0)
    {
        int sCount = Count;
        if (cur.CompareTo(Attendees[mid]) < 0)
        {
            int NCount = sCount / 2;
            mid = NCount / 2 - 1;    
        }
        if (cur.CompareTo(Attendees[mid]) > 0)
        {
            int Start = mid +1;
            mid = (Start + sCount) / 2;
        }
        else
            break;

        cur = Attendees[mid];                
    }
    if (cur.CompareTo(Attendees[x]) == 0)
        return mid;
    else 
        return -1;
}
```

Can anyone help me find out why my binary search isn't working? I'm very new to programming so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If this is not homework, be aware that there is an `Array.BinarySearch` method you can make use of.

Comment: Im currently sitting in class and the task is to program it and lecturer isnt much help when i ask her to explain it.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"? Is `Attendees` sorted? You need to be sure that it is sorted, otherwise binary search doesn't work. You need to make sure that the elements "left of" x return a smaller value in `CompareTo` than the values "right of" x.

Comment: You don't seem to be reducing the size of each gap... you're always looking to move by something based around `sCount` ( == `Count`)... the gap never seems to reduce... But basically: add some debugging: write out the `mid` each iteration so you can see what it is doing.

Comment: You aren't very helpful in explaining either. That is, explaining your problem. "Doesn't work" isn't an adequate error description. If it would work you wouldn't be posting it...

Comment: Yeah attendees is sorting but when i run it i think im landing up in an endless loop. My return isnt printing when im asking it to... I beleive there is an error in my while loop but cant seem to see it my self...

Comment: Thanks Marc. I'll focus on that a bit more. :)

Comment: Stick a breakpoint in the code and find out whats actually going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you didn't really grasp what binary search is about. In your code you are searching at which position element `x` is in an array - guess what? It's at position `x`!

What binary search is about is to find out the index of an element. Soooo you need to search for a given `Student`:

```
public int BinarySearch(Student student)
{
    // Search the entire range
    int min = 0;
    int max = Attendees.Length;
    int mid = 0;

    do
    {
        // Find the pivot element
        mid = min + ((max - min) / 2);

        // Compare
        int comparison = student.CompareTo(Attendees[mid]);
        if (comparison < 0)
        {
            max = mid;
        }
        if (comparison > 0)
        {
            min = mid;
        }
    }
    while (min < max && comparison != 0);

    if (comparison != 0)
        return -1;
    return mid;
}
```

This code may not work 100% as I haven't tried it and wrote it off my head, but it will point you in the right direction. Now, use the debugger on this code and single step through it to see whether it works as expected.