# Insert only new or edited values to rows

Tags: sql

I have got an attendance table as follows.

```
ID         Date        Time
==         ====        ====
1          01/01/2013  17:00:00
1          01/01/2013  22:00:00
```

These table will then get process by a stored procedure that calculate the total hours, deduction, rates etc..etc..  which will be stored in another table with following result as example.

```
ID         Date          TimeIn         TimeOut       Thours         Salary
==         ====          ======         =======       ======         ======
 1         01/01/2013     17:00         22:00          5             $50
```

What we have done now is to run a select if exist.  Then delete table.  in order to update edited entries in the first table, ie, miss punches..

The second table will then get process through another stored procedure to do time rounding, as well as to add tag depending on the results etc.. and then stored in a bigger tables which contain fields like incentive, overtime, advance etc..  etc..  where this table will be use for final insertion of additional data through a windows form.

Now, we're stuck with a situation when we're trying to only add new rows to the 3rd table. as 2nd table always get's deleted and recreated on update, and doing exist update etc don't seem to work, and don't seem to be able to depend on unique key for the 2nd table as it will get recreated on update.

Appreciate any suggestion on how we can keep the 3rd table for user edit..

Comment: Is it possible that you are sitting in the same class as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747263/c-sharp-binary-search)?

Comment: Ah.  No..  I have tried several method on my own before posting, and am asking for "Suggestion"  not solution.  Thanks :)

Comment: OK, I was just wondering because you both talked about attendees. When asking for suggestions, it is always a good idea to include what you already tried and why it didn't work for you. Like this, people can concentrate on what you haven't tried yet - or can show you why your attempts failed and what has to be changed to make them work.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I believe my mind is in a mess now, but having said.  I am not an expert, and lack experience.  maybe just need some rest, and re-think the whole thing all over, maybe start joining the first table to store the in out time in a single row instate of 2 rows.  Ahhhhh!!!!

Comment: Taking a step back is always a good idea when you are stumped.

Answer (score 0):

just add the id from the 1st table to 2nd table and also the customer or whoever attendance you are doing to second table so that u should not delte the second table entries while updating

just check the id of the person in the second table matching the id of the first table

then the third to have the second table id as well

Comment: Hello.  Thanks for the suggestion.  But that didn't work, as I have mention.  The first and 2nd tables get removed and recreated after edit.  Hence, the ID won't be of much help.  but I did menage to get it working using merge on the userID and the first clockin time, where when useID and clockin time date match.  Update, when not match then do an insert..